# Why am I getting the wrong sign on my cos(x) approximation?

Tags: matlab, math

I am writing a Matlab script that will approximate `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` using their Maclaurin polynomials.

When I input 
`arg = (5*pi)/4` I expect to get the correct approximations for

```
sin((5*pi)/4) = -0.7071067811865474617

cos((5*pi)/4) = -0.7071067811865476838.
```

Instead I get the following when running the script:

```
Approximation of sin(3.92699)    >> -0.7071067811865474617
Actual sin(3.92699)               = -0.7071067811865474617
Error approximately               = 0.0000000000000000000 (0)
----------------------------------------------------------
Approximation of cos(3.92699)    >> 0.7071067811865474617
Actual cos(3.92699)               = -0.7071067811865476838
Error approximately               = 0.0000000000000001110 (1.1102e-16)
```

I am getting the correct answers for sin but incorrect for cosine when the argument (angle) is in quadrant 3 or 4. The problem is that I am getting the wrong sign on the cos(arg) value. Where have I messed up?

---

CalculatorForSineCosine.m

```
% Argument for sine/cosine in radians.
arg = (5*pi)/4;

% Move the argument x so it's within [0, pi/2].
newArg = moveArgumentV2(arg);

% Calculate what degree we need for our Taylorpolynomial.
TOL = 0; % If 0, assume we want Machine Epsilon.
r = findDegreeV2(TOL);

% Plot nth degree Taylorpolynomial around x = 0 for sine.
% and calculate approximation of sin(x).
[approximatedSin, errorSin] = sin_taylorV2(r, newArg);
eS = num2str(errorSin); % errorSin in string format

% Plot nth degree Taylorpolynomial around x = 0 for cosine.
% and calculate approximation of cos(x).
[approximatedCos, errorCos] = cos_taylorV2(r, newArg);
eC = num2str(errorCos); % errorCos in string format

% Print out the result.
fprintf('\nApproximation of sin(%.5f)\t >> %.19f\n', arg, approximatedSin);
fprintf('Actual sin(%.5f)\t\t\t\t  = %.19f\n', arg, sin(arg));
fprintf('Error approximately\t\t\t\t  = %.19f (%s)\n', errorSin, eS);
disp("----------------------------------------------------------")
fprintf('Approximation of cos(%.5f)\t >> %.19f\n', arg, approximatedCos);
fprintf('Actual cos(%.5f)\t\t\t\t  = %.19f\n', arg, cos(arg));
fprintf('Error approximately\t\t\t\t  = %.19f (%s)\n\n', errorCos, eC);
```

sin_taylorV2.m

```
function [approximatedSin, errorSin] = sin_taylorV2(r, x)
%% sss

    % Q_2n+1(x) where 2n+1 = degree of polynomial.
    n = (r - 1)/2;

    % Approximate sin(x) using its Taylorpolynomial.
    approximatedSin = 0;
    for k = 0:n
        approximatedSin = approximatedSin + (((-1).^k) .* (x.^(2.*k+1)))./(factorial(2.*k+1));
    end

    % Calculate the error.
    errorSin = abs(sin(x) - approximatedSin);

end
```

cos_taylorV2.m

```
function [approximatedCos, errorCos] = cos_taylorV2(r, x)
%% sss

    % Q_2n+1(x) where 2n+1 = degree of polynomial and n = # terms.
    n = (r - 1)/2;

    % Approximate cos(x) using its Taylorpolynomial.
    approximatedCos = 0;
    for k = 0:n
        approximatedCos = approximatedCos + (((-1).^k) .* (x.^(2.*k)))./(factorial(2.*k));
    end

    % Calculate the error.
    errorCos = abs(cos(x) - approximatedCos);

end
```

moveArgumentV2.m

```
function newArg = moveArgumentV2(arg)
%% Moves the argument x to the interval [0, pi/2].

    % Make use of sines periodocity and choose n as ceil( (x-pi)/2pi) )
    n = ceil((arg-pi)/(2*pi));
    x1 = arg - 2*pi*n; % New angle will be in [-pi, pi]

    x2 = abs(x1); % Angle will be in [0, pi]
    if (x2 < pi/2) && (x2 > 0)
        x3 = x2;
    else
        x3 = pi - x2;
    end
    newArg = x3*sign(x1); % Angle will be in [0, pi/2]

end
```

Comment: I bet `moveArgumentV2` is wrong. Just from a cursory look, not sure exactly. But using `abs` and `sign` to get something to be in [0,pi/2] cannot be right. Did you test that function?

Comment: Also, if your input is in the range `[0, pi/2]`, how do you expect the cosine to give a negative value? Note that you've got the wrong sign, but your function computes an error "Error approximately = 0.0000000000000001110 (1.1102e-16)"!

Comment: @CrisLuengo
1) For the sine function we can utilize its periodicity t write sin(x) = sin(x - 2pi*n) where n is an integer.
2) If we choose n = ceil( (x-pi)/(2pi) ), the minimum integer bigger than or equal to (x-pi)/(2pi), we will have that x1 = x - 2pin will be somewhere on the interval [-pi, pi].
3)  We can then utilize that the sine function is odd, which gives sin(x1) = sgn(x1)sin(x2) where x2 = abs(x1) in [0, pi].
4) Lastly we can utilize the supplement angle identity for the sine function and get sin(x2) = sin(x3) where x3 = x2 if x2 in [0, pi/2] and x3 = pi - x2 if x2 in (pi/2, pi].

Comment: @CrisLuengo

The method comes straight from my professors book.

Comment: @CrisLuengo

So we can calculate sin(x) by first calculating sin(x3), where x3 is guaranteely somewhere on the interval [0, pi/2] and after that multiply with the right sign, sgn(x1). Using basic properties of the sine function we can calculate the value for any argument by calculating sin(x) for an argument that is on the interval [0, pi/2].

Comment: So where you say `newArg = x3*sign(x1); % Angle will be in [0, pi/2]`, you are actually getting a value in the range `[-pi/2, pi/2]`. In any case, your result for `sin` is correct, it's the `cos` one that is wrong. Your description in the comments here don't hold up for `cos`, which is an even function. Why not compute `cos(x) = sin(x+pi/2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tried:

```matlab
x = -3*pi:0.01:3*pi;
y = x;
for ii=1:numel(y)
   y(ii) = moveArgumentV2(y(ii)); % not vectorized
end
plot(sin(x))
hold on
plot(sin(y))
```

Both `sin(x)` and `sin(y)` produce the same plot. But:

```matlab
plot(cos(x))
hold on
plot(cos(y))
```

Now we see that `cos(x)` and `cos(y)` are not the same! This is because `moveArgumentV2` changes the angle to be in the first and fourth quadrant (in the range `[-pi/2, pi/2]`), which is what you need for the `sin` function, but is not adequate for the `cos` function.

I would modify `sin_taylorV2` and `cos_taylorV2` to call `moveArgumentV2`, so you don't rely on the caller to know what the valid input range is. In `cos_taylorV2` you would need to call it this way:

```matlab
   x = moveArgumentV2(x+pi/2) - pi/2;
```

and in `sin_taylorV2` you'd call it the same way you do now.

Or, better, write `cos_taylorV2` in terms of `sin_taylorV2`, which we know to be correct. This avoids code duplication.

Comment: Hi again! Thank you for the feedback. This has solved my problem. I am just wondering if you could give a short explanation as to why I need to call moveArgumentV2 with (x+pi/2) - pi/2? It does work, but I do not entirely understand why. I am aware that cos(x) = sin(x + pi/2), we can describe cosine as a sine functions that is phase shifted pi/2 rad.

Comment: @Fotan: In the range [-pi/2,pi/2] cos(x) is positive. By limiting x to that range you cannot get negative outputs. Did you copy-paste the code I posted here? It illustrates this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to notice two things in your code.

First, you don't need the `moveArgumentV2(arg)` function, as, if you remember, the radius of convergence for the Maclaurin/Taylor series of the `sin(x)`/`cos(x)` is [the set of all real numbers](https://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/the-maclaurin-expansion-of-cosx/). That means the series should converge for any real `x`, disregarding the [round-off errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) inherently to every arithmetic operations done in a computer.

As a matter of fact, following your code, we can write a function that approximates the cos as:

```
function y = mycos(x,n)
    y = 0;

    for k=0:n
        term = (-1)^k*x.^(2*k)/factorial(2*k);
        y = y + term;
    end

end
```

Notice this function works for values outside the range `[-pi,pi]`:

```
x = -10*pi:0.1:10*pi;
ye = cos(x) % exact value
ya = mycos(x,100) % approximated value
plot(x,ye,x,ya,'o')
```

[image]

The values returned by the `mycos` function are close to the exact value given by the `cos` built-in function. This happens because I calculated the approximation with the first 100 terms. The error, however, for higher values of x, is extremely large if we use just a few terms.

```
ya = mycos(x,10) % approximated value with 10 terms only
plot(x,ye-ya); title('error')
```

[image]

The problem now is that we can't just increase the number of terms without running in another problem.
If we increase the number of points, the `mycos` function crumbles due to round-off errors, because of the `factorial` function that overflows. A good idea is to try to change your code in order to avoid the use of the factorial function. Notice the recurrence between sucessive terms in the Maclaurin expansion of the `cos` function, and you can create another function without the use of the `factorial`:

```
function y = mycos2(x,n)
    term = 1;
    y = 1;

    for k=1:n
        term = -term.*x.^2/(2*k-1)/(2*k);
        y = y + term;
    end
end
```

Here, we calculate each term in the series expansion from the previous calculated term. We avoid the calculation of the factorial and make use of what we already have. This speeds the code and avoids overflow. As a matter of fact, if we now calculate the `cos` approximation with 500 terms, we get:

```
x = -10*pi:0.5:10*pi;
ye = cos(x); % exact value
ya = mycos(x,500); % approximated value
ya2 = mycos2(x,500); % approximated value
plot(x,ye,x,ya,'x',x,ya2,'s')
legend('ye','ya','ya2')
```

[image]

Notice in this figure the `x` marks are the calculations done with the `mycos` function, while the `o` marks are done without using the `factorial` function. The first function crumbles for values outside the range [-2,2], but the second one runs just fine. It works even when I use `1e5` terms. Increasing the number of terms reduces the errors, so you can estimate how much terms you will use on an approximation, given a desired tolerance. If this number is greater than `170`, the first function will not work properly.

`factorial(170)` returns `7.2574e+306`, but `factorial(171)` returns `Inf`, so any value that should be calculated with more than 170 terms will have problems in the first function. **Avoid the calculation of factorial at all costs.**

Comment: "Avoid the calculation of factorial at all costs." - absolutely correct.